# powershell keep last 31 files

Tags: powershell, backup

I'm using this powershell command to keep only backup files that are 31 days old.

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  “d:\Backup\hl” –Recurse | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime –lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

My question is if the daily backup was to fail and I checked the backup folder e.g after a month, the powershell script would delete all or most of the backups because they are older then 31 days.

Is it possible to change the powershell command to keep the last 31 files depending on lastwritetime , but not because they are within 31 days old?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, I'm not sure how this will behave with your recurse parameter but assume it is working correctly so I have left it in the example:

`Get-ChildItem –Path  “d:\Backup\hl” –Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime –Descending | Select-Object -Skip 31 | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`

Comment: Thanks, I have tested this with -whatif and it says it will delete 16 folders which it shouldn't be doing. There are 31 folders with 1 file inside each folder. By running the command it theoretically shouldn't delete anything as there is already 31 files?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is the 1 file inside each of the 31 folders?

Comment: Yes I guess so. That's what I meant about using the `recurse` parameter, likely to have unexpected results. Look at the other answer as he has edited to exclude directories.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by `LastWriteTime` and skip the first 31 files. When using `-Recurse`, foldernames would also appear in the result. So to keep the last 31 FILES, you need to exclude the folder-items using `Where-Object`, like:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  “d:\Backup\hl” –Recurse |
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
Select-Object -Skip 31 |
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```